# trying to ramp back up with nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I played around with Nativescript a bit before v5.0 was released.  I watched a YouTube vid earlier today on NS5 and it looks like the platform has taken big steps in regards to integration and streamlining.

If I was using NS pre-v5 then would it make sense to do a complete uninstall/reinstall to start out with a blank slate?  Can you point me to a good url to help ensure that I get the required setup fully squared away?  Also, I watched a bit of the following vid on using the Nativescript extension within VS Code:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/KQHJewS3tqA?autoplay=1

This vid shows multiple Launch Configuration options in a dropdown in the Debug panel.  In this vid, 1 of the options displayed is:

"Launch on Android Emulator"

But the closest option that my VS Code instance displays is:

"Launch on Android"

What do I need to do to be able to get "Launch on Android Emulator" to display within the Launch Configuration options dropdown in my VS Code environment?

Comment: if you want to launch a nativescript app with debug mode, you need to use the debug command `tns run android --debug`

Comment: The video you are referring to is almost 3 years old. The option was renamed. Launch on Android will launch app on the first available Android device or emulator, you may set a device index or id by updating tnsArgs attribute in the launch.json file.